# "No Device Drivers Found" when trying to install Windows 7 onto a Samsung 860 Evo SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, windows-installation, windows-installer

I am trying to install Windows 7 onto a Samsung 860 Evo SSD, but I have been getting "No Device Drivers Found" after I click "Install Windows." I have been using this guide for many years and have installed multiple Samsung 850 Evo SSDs in the same way with no issues https://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/ but am now getting these errors.

I am currently using MBR with a single partition.  I also am trying to install Windows with other drives in the same machine (including my my boot drive).  The drive in SLOT 5.  The BIOS set to UEFI.  I am not sure if I should disconnect all of the other drives, and if it matters which Slot have the have drive connected to?

I am wondering if anyone has any advice on what could be going on?  I did read a few posts about GPT and what seemed to be a multiple drive issue, so I wonder if disconnecting the other drives would do something.  I would try GPT, but this is the second time I ran into this issue when installing windows, and the last time was with a 970 NVME, to which I got to the same point of "No Device Drivers Found," until I tried switching from MBR to GPT, and now I cannot load windows at all anymore so I rather not risk that happening with this Samsung 860 SSD.

Are any drivers needed for a regular 860 SSD, since I don't recall the 850s needing any?

Also to note, this is a new motherboard, that I'm trying to install the drive on.  I do have another computer with a motherboard that I believe did work, but not sure if I can access to it.

I mention about the motherboard because I was thinking about running the windows setup from one of the drives that currently does work, and then trying to install windows onto the new drive.  I am curious if that would work as well?  I wanted to be careful not to delete anything, but I believe that just running the setup and installing onto another drive shouldn't be an issue, would it?

Any help is appreciated, thank you everyone!

EDIT:  I tried using one of the older drives where the guide worked, and I was able to run the windows installer perfectly fine, and was able to install onto the new drive. The only issue is that for some reason I could only boot into the new drive, from the old one.  Aka I boot into the old drive, and then there is would be 2 "Windows 7" options and then the installer option.  This is obviously not what I want, but the installer does still work on the old SSD, with this current machine, so it's odd why the installer wont work on the new ssd itself.  The files are the same files that were copied from the original files on my external hard drive.  I will see if I can get the original copies to maybe work.

EDIT2:  I realized that I was using my old laptop and installing the files on the disc onto the hard drive, and then booting the drive.  The files I have now I believe were copied from one of the drives, but at the same time I have the setup exe and the other files, so maybe I copied everything directly from the disc, I'm not sure... Either way this isn't working out.

Comment: Is it possible that it has no drivers for the CONTROLLER on the new motherboard and not the drive itself?

Comment: Agreed. Can you slipstream drivers from a previous, working Windows 7 install onto your ISO before trying to install it again? I know it's a lot of work for a 2KB driver file, but from 1 generation to the next, Samsung SSDs get pickier and pickier when it comes to drivers. Also, I'm surprised you're installing on a single partition. Windows 7 and up usually create two, or even three partitions, one of them with Windows PE, the other for the bootloader; sometimes, a fourth one is even added as some kind of swap for install, and never deleted. Did you decide on the number of partitions yourself?

Comment: Each drive can be formatted with a GPT partition table or an MBR Partition table, but only one per drive. However, you can mix and match GPT and MBR drives in Windows.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am not sure, but I will say that I did try to use the installation from the 2nd drive I used this guide on, and it actually allowed me to boot up and install windows, but the issue is that the new install was tied to the old hard drive, and needed the bootmgr on the new drive in order to work, which is possible to do, but it's a weird setup like that.  Not sure what driver it could be looking for as I'm using the same method and same files, with no luck.

Comment: @Didier I'm using the same files as I've been using, but on a different hard drive, so I might try the original files, but I don't know why they would magically work, but who knows.  As I mentioned to Señor, I was able to use another drive to install onto, so I don't think it's the SSD drivers or the SSD itself.  I dfid a single partition because that's all I needeed, bu tI realize It was split on my current, so I created a 4gb partition for the boot files, but I still have no luck getting the installer to work on the new drive... Very odd/annoying.

Comment: I just remembered that I was originally using the installation disc to get the files, but now I am using files from one of the installations, which might be why there is an issue, I'm not sure.

Comment: Try disconnecting other drives during install.

Comment: @Moab I thought that might be it, but the older drive worked fine installing onto the new drive with 2 drives installed, so I'm not sure why it would be different in this case.  Maybe the iso file would work better.

Comment: If you're installing from a DVD, it's going to be difficult to slipstream anything, contrarily to USB where adding the missing files right in the middle of the install files can be done easily. I did just that two weeks ago on a Lenovo laptop whose WiFi adapter wouldn't install. It didn't have Ethernet. As for you, I have the same SSD on my own Lenovo, but I installed Windows 10 on it, with not a trace of hiccup. Windows 7 support has been dropped, so if the SSD is brand-new, it's *possible* that the newest firmware forbids you to install a not-supported OS. AHCI enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @Didier I ended up being able to install windows 7 home from another one of the booted hard drives, but it now only allows me to boot from the alrady booted ssd, that uses the new ssd for storage/os.  I will try a usb key, I do believe the iso I ahve works, but I do believe I can download the win 7 iso directly from microsoft?  I've heard that "Rufus" is a good iso to usb mount program?  It's just a real shame that this other method isn't working, but I believe it's because I used to grab the files directly from the CD, but now it's just the files that I copied from the CD.shouldn't matter tho

Comment: This freeware (here: https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool) will allow you to download legal copies of any recent version of Windows (7, 8, 8.1, 10) from Microsoft's website. You can minimize the ad window and access the main window easily, then check which version of Windows you want. The program will download it for you directly from a Microsoft server. Be sure to choose the right version (32-bit or 64-bit), because those ISOs weigh almost 3GB each.